# Javascript modal DOM updating necessary?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I have some functions in my Javascript code that will perform long operations such as painting various images to a canvas. While these functions are happening, I do not want the user to be able to access buttons on the UI, so I place a large modal div over everything to cover up the buttons while the process is taking place. I soon realized however that since the code is continuous, the UI never actually has a chance to update, and the modal div never actually appears since it is removed at the end of the process.

My question is, is it really necessary to cover up the UI in this type of scenario? If the user does press another button while the operation is being performed, will the new process wait until the previous process is done before starting? Or perhaps since the modal UI was *supposed* to be up at the moment they clicked the UI, the modal will prevent the new process from starting. The alternative is that I could set a time out directly after bringing the modal div up giving the UI time to update before beginning the process, but I am not sure that this is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need the cover div, and no, new processes won't wait until the previous process is done before starting (unless you coded them to do so).

A simple trick to force a repaint is to use `setTimeout` with `0` milliseconds. The re-layout should happen as soon as possible.

Comment: not *exactly* "immediately" but it's more like "as soon as possible"

Comment: Thanks for the bounty, I wasn't expecting it!

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, do your own task control. When you start "single of a kind" operation - raise some flag indicating that it is in progress. If you receive a message from some UI element initiating this task again just `return`. When done, remove flag.

Answer (score 1):

you do need the div, because of the way engines execute javascript. It's quite interesting if you want to read it - written by non other than John Resig (excuse me if i am over-exaggerating, hehe) http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/. Although it's about timers and intervals,

If you're in no mood to read, here's the summary:
The code is executed in the same thread, and whenever the browser finds time, it pauses the current code, and starts something else - execution itself doesn't halt - the path of it changes, temporarily. I highly recommend you read the full post.

Answer (score 1):

As @Parth pointed, browsers run javascript into a single thread, thus, if the `<div>` overlay is not present, the UI events will be triggered, but will remain in queue until the long-time running function completes. Usually, though, this behavior is not expected. If you want to freeze UI, just keep the `<div>` overlay.

If you want to give the browser a chance to update UI (or allow the user to cancel processing), you must break the long running function logic into various function calls and chain them using `window.setTimeout calls`. There are several ways to implement this pattern, but I like the non-recursive closured queue aproach:

```
// this will block UI until all images are painted:
function paintAll(arImg) {
    for(var i=0; i<arImg.length; i++) paintSingle(arImg[i]);
}

// this will block UI only while each image is painted:
function paintAll(arImg) {
    // copy arImg to queue not to modify the input parameter
    var queue = arImg.slice(0);

    // apply the paint function to the first element, remove it from queue
    // and set the runner function to run again after 5 milliseconds
    // (this will allow the UI thread to run between each runner call)
    var runner = function() {
        // check any UI based condition to abort running:
        if(!checkUiBasedCondition()) return;

        if(!queue.length) return;
        paintSingle(queue.shift());
        window.setTimeout(runner, 5);
    }

    // call runner to initiate the processing
    runner();
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: I like your answer and was about to upvote it, when I saw the w3schools link at the end. Please don't trust them! See this: http://w3fools.com

Comment: Thank you for the information, @bfavaretto. I agree with you that the name of this site can mislead the user to imply it's related with W3C. That's a bad practice and should not be endorsed. By the way: I changed the references to mozilla.org :)